# Sculptor smurf and sledgehammer smurf

Tags: the-smurfs

I'm trying to find proof (a reference) that sculptor smurf and sledgehammer smurf are not the same character (it's easy to find images of them where the hammer is very different & sculptor has a scalpel). Am I wrong? And sorry if I'm not accurate about their names!

Also, my friend says sledgehammer smurf is grouchy, which I think is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

1. The head of Sledgehammer Smurf's two-handed maul is much larger than Sculptor Smurf's one-handed mallet and the shaft/handle is longer.
2. Sculptor Smurf typically carries his mallet in one hand with a sculptor's chisel in the other. Sledgehammer Smurf is often depicted dragging his maul around behind him using two hands.
3. Sculptor Smurf wears an artist's smock with white booted leggings; Sledgehammer Smurf wears white booted leggings and no shirt.
4. Sculptor Smurf speaks with a French accent like his brother, Painter Smurf. However, I have no recollection of Sledgehammer Smurf's speech inflections.

[image]
[image]

---

<sub>FWIW, There is usually much more confusion between Sledgehammer Smurf and Mallet Smurf than either of them and Sculptor Smurf.</sub>

Comment: And how about grouchy/Sledgehammer? (Mallet usually has a gift/package)